# Reporting attendance with NFC capable devices, is this approach feasable?

Tags: android, nfc

I was introduced recently to NFC and felt immediately engaged by its applications and usability. I was discussing some ideas with a friend of mine who employs a dispersed workforce and how to solve his problem with attendance reporting.
For what I've seen and read, the typical implementation for an attendance system using NFC capable devices or cards follows the following principle:

- Terminal at the attendance point (think of workplace) with connection
  to a server.
- An employee arrives, carrying a NFC card/tag or NFC capable device
  (Android), and initiates transaction with the terminal.
- The terminal receives worker information and reports attendance.

---

Now let's consider a different approach for remote places.

- A NFC tag/card is secured to a wall to avoid removal, but offers easy
  access. An    employee uses a NFC capable device (Android) to report
  his arrival.
- The NFC tag contains information about the locale, the device
  (Android) extracts this information and consequently communicates
  with a server (API) reporting it's attendance.

Does it sounds reasonable?

How easy would it be for someone to clone the NFC tag/card and report attendance for that specific locale, from anywhere?

If it is feasible, what type of tags/cards should I consider using, also any pointers about the security?

I would be highly appreciate for any type of help or someone pointing me to the right direction/resources. Many thanks!

**UPDATE:**

According to mictter, JavaCards is the way to go.

> I would use some kind of phone-card muthual authentication instead of plain NDEF tags. For example, a JavaCard app would transmit the information about locale only after a successful authentication: this way, we would be protected about cloning attacks. The smartphone could still be vulnerable if it had to keep the card keys in some app: this vulnerability can be solved by making the server communicate directly with the card and read the locale information directly. The phone would act just as a proxy.

However I see that [MIFARE DESFire EV1](http://www.mifare.net/en/products/mifare-smartcard-ic-s/mifare-desfire-ev1/) can also hold up to 28 applications, would it be a good alternative? Mifare's SDK seems highly attractive to simplify the android app implementation.

Comment: (I am not sure it is good etiquette to mention this, so if it is not, please point it to me and I will delete this comment.) In the company I'm working for we have published a set of tools for quick prototyping of JavaCard applets on contactless cards, have a look: https://developer.fidesmo.com/

Comment: I was actually struggling to get started with it, thank you for the hint. Seems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea does not only sound reasonable, but it has been put into practice I believe by several companies and startups. These guys (http://www.echeckinservices.com/ - no relation and I don't know if they are still in business) designed a tag-based system to control attendance quite finely grained, for example to make sure that a security guard makes the rounds as he should, interacting with tags all around the facility. NFC tags are low-cost enough that you can put them everywhere.

To avoid that a too enterprising employee clones tags and lives an easy life from then on :), I would use some kind of phone-card muthual authentication instead of plain NDEF tags. For example, a JavaCard app would transmit the information about locale only after a successful authentication: this way, we would be protected about cloning attacks.
The smartphone could still be vulnerable if it had to keep the card keys in some app: this vulnerability can be solved by making the server communicate directly with the card and read the locale information directly. The phone would act just as a proxy.

Comment: Hi mictter, thks for the reply. Sorry my ignorance, but wouldn't it also be easy to clone a JavaCard or a MIFARE DESFire tag for example?

Comment: I have been reading a bit about JavaCards and MIFARE NFC and understand the differences now (ignore my last comment). JavaCards seem the way to go. Do you know if there are any known any complications with Android devices communicating with Java Cards?

Comment: Hi pelican_george! In my experience, JavaCard is the technology having the least compatibility problems with Android devices. For example, MIFARE Classic only works with phones having an NFC chipset made by NXP. 
Cloning a JavaCard would not be possible without the keys. You would need to think well what information to store in the card: for example a private key to sign a timestamp generated by the phone, that can be verified by the server that holds the public key.